# Preventing update loops for multiple databases using CDC

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, cdc

We have a number of legacy systems that we're unable to make changes to - however, we want to start taking data changes from these systems and applying them automatically to other systems.

We're thinking of some form of service bus (no specific tech picked yet) sitting in the middle, and a set of bus adapters (one per legacy application) to translate between database specific concepts and general update messages.

One area I've been looking at is using Change Data Capture (CDC) to monitor update activity in the legacy databases, and use that information to construct appropriate messages. However, I have a concern - how best could I, as a consumer of CDC information, distinguish changes applied by the application vs changes applied by the bus adapter on receipt of messages - because otherwise, the first update that gets distributed by the bus will get re-distributed by every receiver when they apply that change to their own system.

If I was implementing "poor mans" CDC - i.e. triggers, then those triggers execute within the context/transaction/connection of the original DML statements - so I could either design them to ignore one particular user (the user applying incoming updates from the bus), or set and detect a session property to similar ignore certain updates.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you're trying to define a message routing structure that works with a design you've already selected (using an [enterprise service bus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_service_bus)) and [a message implementation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_data_capture) that you can use to flow data off your legacy systems that *only* forward-ports changes to your newer systems.

The difficulty is you're trying to apply changes in such a way that they don't themselves generate a CDC message from the clients receiving the data bundle from your legacy systems. In fact, all you're concerned about is having your newer systems consume the data and not propagate messages back to your bus, creating unnecessary crosstalk that might exponentiate, overloading your infrastructure.

The secret is [how MSSQL's CDC features reconcile changes](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/166250/Microsoft-SQL-Server-2008-Change-Data-Capture-CDC) as they propagate through the network. Specifically, note this caveat:

> All the changes are logged in terms of LSN or Log Sequence Number. SQL
>   distinctly identifies each operation of DML via a Log Sequence Number.
>   Any committed modifications on any tables are recorded in the
>   transaction log of the database with a specific LSN provided by SQL
>   Server. The __$operationcolumn values are: 1 = delete, 2 = insert, 3 =
>   update (values before update), 4 = update (values after update).
>
> cdc.fn_cdc_get_net_changes_dbo_Employee gives us all the records net
>   changed falling between the LSN we provide in the function. We have
>   three records returned by the net_change function; there was a delete,
>   an insert, and two updates, but on the same record. In case of the
>   updated record, it simply shows the net changed value after both the
>   updates are complete.
>
> For getting all the changes, execute
>   cdc.fn_cdc_get_all_changes_dbo_Employee; there are options either to
>   pass 'ALL' or 'ALL UPDATE OLD'. The 'ALL' option provides all the
>   changes, but for updates, it provides the after updated values. Hence
>   we find two records for updates. We have one record showing the first
>   update when Jason was updated to Nichole, and one record when Nichole
>   was updated to EMMA.

While this documentation is somewhat terse and difficult to understand, it appears that changes are logged and reconciled in LSN order. Competing changes *should* be discarded by this system, allowing your consistency model to work effectively.

Note also:

> CDC is by default disabled and must be enabled at the database level
>   followed by enabling on the table.

Option B then becomes obvious: institute CDC on your legacy systems, then use your service bus to translate these changes into updates that aren't bound to CDC (using, for example, raw transactional update statements). This should allow for the one-way flow of data that you seek from the design of your system.

For additional methods of reconciling changes, consider the concepts raised by [this Wikipedia article on "eventual consistency"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eventual_consistency). Best of luck with your internal database messaging system.